# react native convert string into array data

Tags: string, react-native

i have string like this:

```
'["wss://mediaslave1-dev-v2.vedax.ai/1L1g5nSOrNBr1fBWBva7","https://mediaslave1-dev-v2.vedax.ai/PMKzhcRhIEugeqowXMpc"]'
```

I want to convert into array, can someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const str ='["wss://mediaslave1-dev-v2.vedax.ai/1L1g5nSOrNBr1fBWBva7","https://mediaslave1-dev-v2.vedax.ai/PMKzhcRhIEugeqowXMpc"]'
const arr = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(arr);
```

You may use `JSON.parse`

Comment: hi, then how can i got each string of this json? Thanks

Comment: you can access the first data arr[0]